# Questions about the indicator function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

I have two questions regarding the indicator function. Let $\lambda$ be a measure and $B$ a measurable set. I encountered the following

$$f(x,\lambda)=1_{B}(x)1_{\{\lambda(B)=3\}}$$

1. I know that the indicator function $1_B(x)$ checks whether $x\in B$ but how does $1_{\{\lambda(B)=3\}}$ work? I assume it is $1$ when the measure of the set $B$ is $3$. But shouldn't there be a parameter $x$ meaning something like $1_{\{\lambda(B)=3\}}(x)$. Does that mean an arbitrary $x$ is always in the set ${\{\lambda(B)=3\}}$ when the equation is true?
2. If $\eta$ is another measure. Is then the following true:
   $$\int 1_{\{\lambda(B)=3\}}\mathrm{d}\eta(dx)=1_{\{\eta(B)=3\}}$$
   If not, how do I integrate it?

Comment: I can't imagine what it would mean.

Comment: @copper.hat I assume it means that the function $1_{\lambda(B)=3}$ is $1$ if the set $B$ has $\lambda$-measure $3$ otherwise it is $0$?

Comment: If it was, I would expect something like $1_{\{B| \lambda B = 3 \}}(B)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many people abuse the notation of the indicator function (admittedly, myself included) and use it to generically mean "equal to one if this statement is true, equal to zero otherwise". So in your case the function is

$$f(x,\lambda)=\begin{cases}
1&\text{if }x\in B\text{ and }\lambda(B)=3,\\
0&\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

Of course, since $f$ is a function not only of $x\in X$, where $(X,\mathcal A)$ is your measurable space, but also of the set of measures $\lambda$ on $\mathcal A$, one could write this in "proper" form:

$$f(x,\lambda)=1_B(x)1_{F^{-1}(\{3\})}(\lambda),$$

where $F$ is the function $\lambda\mapsto\lambda(B)$.

To answer your second question, $1_{\{\lambda(B)=3\}}$ is not a function of $x$, so can be treated as constant. This implies

$$\int_X1_{\{\lambda(B)=3\}}\eta(dx)=1_{\{\lambda(B)=3\}}\eta(X).$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, that explains everything!